# Can I see the contents of the String Table in a running process?

Tags: c#, .net, string, cil, string-table

Is there any way I can see the contents of the string table in a running .NET application?

I want to compare a console application with vanilla string concatinations and one using the string builder.

Comment: @stuartd  I *think* that question is about string literals in an assembly, I'm wanting the strings cached at run time by the framework.

Comment: "The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system." -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ClrMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) to attach to a process and retrieve information from it. Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("myapp.exe").FirstOrDefault();
using (var target = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(proc.Id, 1000))
{
    var runtime = target.ClrVersions[0].CreateRuntime();
    var heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    foreach (var obj in heap.EnumerateObjectAddresses())
    {
        var type = heap.GetObjectType(obj);
        if (type.Name == "System.String")
        {
            var value = (string)type.GetValue(obj);
            // Write value to disk or something.
        }
    }
}
```